# Why is getchar_unlocked() faster than alternatives?

Tags: c++, getchar

I know how this code works but i could not find why this code faster than other i/o methords???

```
int read_int() {
  char c = getchar_unlocked();
  while(c<'0' || c>'9') c = getchar_unlocked();
  int ret = 0;
  while(c>='0' && c<='9') {
    ret = 10 * ret + c - 48;
    c = getchar_unlocked();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: getchar_unlocked is not thread safe according to: https://www.quora.com/How-and-when-do-I-use-getchar_unlocked-in-C
Not being thread safe can explain the difference in running time.

Comment: `getchar_unlocked()` is not a standard function in C++.   Your will need to read relevant documentation for that function - whatever it is - to understand how it works and what that means for performance.

Comment: `ret = 10 * ret + c - 48;` -- ASCII assumption / magic number detected.

Comment: And `c - 48`?  That's not going to work if the character set changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d\n", &x)` has to parse the format string and lock the stream before and after the reading.

`std::cin >> x` might do locking too, and it might have to sync with `stdin`, and it might need to go through some abstraction layers.

With the above, you only do one type of input parsing (so no need to parse a format string and decide what to do based on that) and most importantly, you don't lock the stream.

Locking streams is mandated by POSIX, and [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams-and-Threads) uses recursive mutexes to prevent multiple threads (even in a single-threaded environment) from accessing the stdin `FILE` simultaneously (which would corrupt it).
These mutexes are quite expensive (your `read_int` should be several (fivish?) times faster than `scanf("%d",&x)`).

---

Regarding your implementation, apart from fixing the magic number issue,
you should probably detect failures in `getchar_unlocked` too and report those failures through a separate channel -- e.g., by returning the parsed integer through a passed-in pointer and using the return status for error reporting.

If you want thread safety, you can still use `getchar_unlocked` to get a speedup compared to `getchar`, but you have to `flockfile(stdin);` and `funlock(stdin);` at the beginning and end (respectively) of your `read_int` function.

Comment: "it uses recursive mutexes" -- what does "recursive" mean in this context?

Comment: @chi Reentrant by the same thread multiple times without causing a deadlock. It's potentially specific to the glibc implementation (amended the answer) as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams-and-Threads . I'm not sure if POSIX mandates that property. It's potentially unnecessary (as is the whole locking requirement, IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Locking between threads is expensive.  This is a non locking IO call.

https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/2667/getchar_unlocked